# csv.DictWriter writeheader() and writerow do not write properly Greek characters in CSV file when displayed in Microsoft Excel

Tags: python, json, csv

Using `python` v3.7.8, I'm trying to read data from `JSON` file and write some data in `CSV`. `JSON` contains Greek and Latin Characters.

Data from `JSON` are read properly (I print them). However, when I'm writing data to `CSV`, Greek characters and not shown properly.

This is my code:

```
import json
import csv

# Opening JSON file to read data
f = open('test_2021-11-22-Andrias_lecture.json', 'r',encoding= 'utf-8')
# returns JSON object as a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

namesRowList=[]
namesColumnList=[]
connectionCountList=[]
connectionCountListTemp=[]
connectionsRow = {'':''}

# Iterating through the json list
for i in data['playerArray']:
    namesRowList.append(i['score'])
    namesColumnList.append(i['score'])
    connectionsRowTemp = {i['score']:''}
    connectionsRow.update(connectionsRowTemp)
    
print(connectionsRow)
        
# Open CSV file to store data
with open('matrix_10_Jan_2022.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    headerList = [''] + namesRowList.copy()
    
    dw = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=';', fieldnames=headerList)
    dw.writeheader()
    
    
    for i in data['playerArray']:
        name = i['score']
        connections = i['connections']
        connectionsRow['']=name
        index = 0
        
        for name in namesRowList:
            for con in connections:
                if (name == con):
                    connectionsRow[name] = 1
                else:
                    connectionsRow[name] = 0
            index = index + 1

        dw.writerow(connectionsRow)
   file.close()
```

Comment: "However, when I'm writing data to CSV, Greek characters and not shown properly." How do you know?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I open the `CSV` file and see them.

Comment: As an aside, the whole point of use `with open(...) as file: ...` is so it will automatically call `file.close()` so you can remove that line

Comment: **How** do you do that exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for `file.close()`. When I print the list in console I can read the Greek characters. Also, in `JSON` file, Greek characters are shown properly. When I open the `CSV` to check the output file, I can't read the characters. My native language is Greek so MS Excel shows properly Greek characters in general.

Comment: Try using `utf-8-sig` for the encoding

Comment: OK, so you are opening it *with excel*. What encoding are you opening the file with?

Comment: @EyalGolan It worked! You can add it as a response to accept it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's the default one.

Comment: @zinon Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel requires the byte order mark (BOM) signature or it will interpret the file in the local ANSI encoding. There is a codec for that, `utf-8-sig`.